# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, multi-boot, ubuntu-11.04

I'm using Windows 7. Now, I need to install Ubuntu 11.04 to the my laptop, but I want to keep Win7 as well.
I'm planning to use a dual boot system; I want to install Ubuntu on separate partition.
I have deleted my Windows empty partition to allocate the space to Ubuntu, but when I'm proceeding with the Ubuntu installation, it won't recognize the empty partition.
Ubuntu shows my full hard disk space as one 50GB partition to install to; however, the installer won't recognize the 50GB empty partition.

Can anyone tell me how to install Ubuntu on my laptop? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install your ubuntu is, installing like a program alongside with your existing windows 7 OS.

Follow these steps carefully.

In windows 7 extract your ubuntu 11.04 iso file using Winrar into your desired partition.
double click wubi.exe

[image]

and choose the partition in installation drive list and specify the amount of installation for your ubuntu,

And assign password then click install .That's it it will automatically add two boot entry option when you start your computer .

[image]

Some times you may receive this error message while runnning wubi.exe ,don't panic just click continue again and again.

[image]

Comment: +1 for not answering with just a link

Answer (score 1):

The following link might be a solution for you
It is a step by step guide plus gives solution and preventions..

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Install_Ubuntu_after_Windows

Comment: Thank you ,Is there a way to recognize specified partition in ubuntu?

Comment: don't know much about it. It would be better if you use the community help for such things. I will help you a lot as it works for me...

Answer (score 1):

May be you have to read [how to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows](http://www.hangged.co.cc/home/tweaks-n-tricks/ubuntu/howtodualbootubuntuandwindows). This might ressolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your data.  Let the Ubuntu installation do it's work.  I just use the Ubuntu install disk and follow what ever it suggests.  No need to do anything prior to following the Ubuntu installation instructions.

Also, I would not have 'deleted my windows empty partition' before using the Ubuntu install disk, because now it won't find any empty partitions to install to.

Comment: Thank you ,I want to install ubuntu on my empty partition , not to the default one,can we do that?